# Returning something other than null

Tags: java, junit, junit4

This is probably a really bad way of writing code but heres a program that calculates the total of each row and print it all in brackets.

```
public static int[] rowsSums(int[][] array) {
    int[][] numArray = {

                            {3, -1,  4,  0},
                            {5,  9, -2,  6},
                            {5,  3,  7, -8}

                       };
    int rowTotal = 0;
    int row2Total = 0;
    int row3Total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numArray[0].length; i++) {
        rowTotal += numArray[0][i];
        row2Total += numArray[1][i]; 
        row3Total += numArray[2][i];
    }

    System.out.println("(" + rowTotal + "," + row2Total + "," + row3Total + ")");
    return null;

}
```

The output without JUnit is:

> (6,18,7)

I am in the process of testing this with JUnit and my code for this:

```
@Test
public void rowsSums() {

    int [] i = new int [] {6, 18, 7};
    assertEquals(i, Exercise2.rowsSums(numArray));
}
```

Yes, I know my output is not supposed to be null because JUnit hates it. What other variable can I return without making JUnit fail or spit an error?

**I have to keep these as it is**

> public static int[] rowsSums(int[][] array) {
>
> int[][] numArray = {

**UPDATE:** No matter what I try, JUnit always comes up with this error [PrntScrn of Error](https://prnt.sc/j4ccd0)

Comment: why not return the string as on output?

Comment: If your method is supposed to return an `int[]`, I'd expect an array containing the sums.

Comment: "*Yes, I know my output is not supposed to be null because JUnit hates it.*" - Could you elaborate? "*What other variable can I return without making JUnit fail or spit an error?*" - Everything that fits your return type.

Comment: You shouldn't be printing in the function. Return the row totals as an integer array, like you already have, then print outside the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return the `int[]` containing the sums, you'd do

```
return new int[] { rowTotal, row2Total, row3Total };
```

That's something you can assert as well then

```
assertArrayEquals(i, Exercise2.rowsSums(numArray));
```

Note that it is good practice to separate calculation and output, ie you should move the `System.out.println` to another function accepting the returned array as a parameter.

Comment: I used this, then I changed something in JUnit code.
`@Test
 public void rowsSums() {
  
  int [] i = new int [] {6, 18, 7};
  Assert.assertArrayEquals(i, Exercise2.rowsSums(numArray));
 } `

Answer (score 1):

If your method is designed to just print a message and not return anything, you should declare its return type to be `void`.

```
public static void rowsSums(int[][] array) { ...
```

Then just remove the `return` statement.

However, based on your test case, it looks like you want to return an array containing the values that you calculated. Instead of having three internal variables to hold totals (`rowTotal`, `row2Total`, and `row3Total`), those variables could be combined into one array where the totals are stored, then returned.

Comment: It seems on my paper. I have to keep it as `public static int[] rowsSums(int[][] array) {`

Comment: @Leon185 In that case, you want to go with the second option and keep your totals in an array, then return that array from your method. (Printing your results can then also be done outside the method.)

Comment: How would I do this as an example?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your method should return the computation performed and not only print a message otherwise you would not have a clear way to test your method.
Besides method names should be verbs/actions and not common names.
So `sum()` would be clearer.

You could return the sum array of each row in your method and assert the result in your unit test :

```
public static int[] sum(int[][] array) {
  ...     
    return new int[] {rowTotal,  row2Total, row3Total};
}
```

And in your test :

```
int[] sumExpected = ...
Assert.assertArrayEquals(sumExpected, Exercise2.sum(numArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[][] numArray = {

            {3, -1,  4,  0},
            {5,  9, -2,  6},
            {5,  3,  7, -8}

};

public static int[] rowsSums(int[][] array) {

    int[] sum =  new int[array.length];

    for (int i=0;i<sum.length; i++)
        sum[i] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sum.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j< array[i].length; j++)
        sum[i] += array[i][j];
    }

    return sum;

}

int[] result = rowsSums(numArray);
```

Comment: It doesnt like this. Underlines it in red

Comment: it's an example of how to do it, not a copy paste code...

Comment: @Leon185 now it's a copy paste code

Answer (score 0):

If you will return array as a result you will be able to use it in your jUnit test and compare expected result with actual.

```
System.out.println("(" + rowTotal + "," + row2Total + "," + row3Total + ")");
int [] result = new int[3];
result[0] = rowTotal;
result[1] = row2Total;
result[2] = row3Total;
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you pass int[][] array to the method, but literally never do anything with it at all?... I'm going to assume you want to use that array structure you passed in order to count each of it's arrays (rows). You also should never mix output with functions. You should return the String, then print it in your main method. As @bill-the-Lizard said, you want to have an array in which holds the row's values and then you would just return an int[] array which contains the rows' counts. You would then have a for loop in your current one which would input the counts into their corresponding array key.

Comment: I should mention, I have no idea how to tag people here

Comment: It's only possible to tag people in comments.